# what is the name of the flower?

Tags: identification

[image]

I saw this flower on the street but I don't know the name of this flower. Could somebody help me to find please?

Comment: Please let us know where you were when you saw. (EX: Miami, Florida) Also, let us know whether it was a wildflower or whether it appeared to be planted by someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's Lantana camara, an evergreen shrub in tropical regions, also found commonly in America

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Featured_picture_candidates/Lantana_flower_and_leaves

More information here about this plant's toxicity (but only if eaten, and particularly the berries; even so, no worse than than over 50% of plants grown in the average garden), and the fact this plant is only evergreen in regions with suitable temperatures

https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/all/lantana-camara/

Comment: With the apparent interest by the OP in the flower, it may be worth noting that this flower is an invasive weed that is toxic to animals.